# send a redirection in java servlet doPost() method

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, response

I am able to get data from doPost() in java servlet and process the data accordingly. After that, i need to send a redirection response which I am not clear about. I intend to send the redirection page to an external php site.Anyone would share with me how could this be achieved? I have tried response.sendRedirection(URL); in doPost(), but it is not working and not redirect me to any new page.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried to see what is actually returned to the browser, using FireBug in FF or wget?

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: How did your code compile with `response.sendRedirection(URL)`? Did you see any method like this in [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

Comment: -1 for not mentioning that your code did not compile at all and not reading the class' javadoc at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is response.sendRedirect() not response.sendRedirection(). That could be why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `response.sendRedirection(URL)`. The method is called `response.sendRedirect(URL)`.

Or do you write something in the output before invoking the response.sendRedirect()? Im not sure how jsp handles this but, for example, in php you only can change the header before any actual output is sent.

Answer (score 0):

use [response.sendRedirect(url)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead of response.sendRedirection(url)